# long_description only contains first line of README.rst

Tags: python, python-3.x, pypi, python-wheel

I am having issues with the README.rst file for packaging this module. I looked up plenty of posts from SO but found nothing helpful.

Currently, I am using a very simple readme for testing

```
pytelemetry
===========

pytelemetry enables remote monitoring and control of embedded
devices. Specifically, pytelemetry implements a custom communication
protocol, based on the PubSub messaging pattern.
```

Here is an overview of the setup.py file

```
here = path.abspath(path.dirname(__file__))
# Get the long description from the README file
with open(path.join(here, 'README0.rst'), encoding='utf-8') as f:
    long_description = f.read()
    print(long_description) # Prints the correct readme

setup(
    name='pytelemetry',

    version='1.1.0',

    description='Lightweight remote monitoring and control of embedded devices',
    long_description=long_description, # Not working !
```

I build the package with `python setup.py bdist_wheel`. With python 3.5.1, wheels 0.24.0 and 0.29.0.
The `print(long_description)` works perfectly fine but when I unzip the generated wheel, the DESCRIPTION.rst file (which I believe should contain the long description) only contains :

```
pytelemetry
```

Which corresponds to the first line of my README.rst. On pypi, I get the same output. Why do I end up with only the first line of my readme in there ?

- Am I correct to think that DESCRIPTION.rst contains whatever is given to setup.py in long_description ?
- How can I fix this problem ?
- How can I debug issues like that in the future ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Wow, that was a dumb issue.

The failing script was

```
try:
    long_description = pypandoc.convert('README.md', 'rst')
except OSError:
    print("Pandoc not found. Long_description conversion failure.")
    import io
    # pandoc is not installed, fallback to using raw contents
    with io.open('README.md', encoding="utf-8") as f:
        long_description = f.read()
```

I added this one line :

```
try:
    long_description = pypandoc.convert('README.md', 'rst')
    long_description = long_description.replace("\r","") # THAT $%^$*($ ONE
except OSError:
    print("Pandoc not found. Long_description conversion failure.")
    import io
    # pandoc is not installed, fallback to using raw contents
    with io.open('README.md', encoding="utf-8") as f:
        long_description = f.read()
```

And now if I decompress the generated wheel, I can see my full readme inside DESCRIPTION.rst ! Yay.
I am not sure what caused this issue though, or if it is pypandoc or the setup function that has an issue.

To find this solution, I went simpy to the pypandoc repo and [had a look at their setup.py file](https://github.com/bebraw/pypandoc/blob/master/setup.py), which does exactly that.